# missing binaries after installing NDK using Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have installed NDK using Android Studio but I cannot find for example:

1. `arm-linux-androideabi-cpp` ,
2. `arm-linux-androideabi-c++`
3. `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.9`
4. `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-ar`
5. `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-nm`

under:

`/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin`

How can I install them?

Thanks

Comment: From the NDK revision history: _"r17c: * GCC is no longer supported. It will be removed in NDK r18."_, _"r18: * GCC has been removed."_

Comment: What do you need them for?